# how to do filtering work by drop down of admin module in magento ?(e.g status----> enabled)

Tags: magento, grid, adminhtml

want to do filtering of product name like status is done.(the product [Samsung,alien] these values are displayed randomly from database,i don't know where its code is written and on which logic its being rendered).
please provide the answer in steps.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure if I understand. You're talking about the 'Manage Products' page in the Magento admin backend, correct? Where are the random product names being displayed?

Comment: Samsung,alien,HTC... which i have added in drop down... >>> P.S:- I have created admin module with module Creator...

Comment: i received the solution .Just added the index data with my database field name (location:/var/www/magento/app/code/local/One/First/Block/Adminhtml/First/Grid.p‌​hp) -->$this->addColumn('select_first',array( 'header' => Mage::helper('first')->__('Product Name'), 'width' => '150px', 'index' => 'proid', 'type' => 'options', 'options' => Mage::getSingleton('first/arrayf')->getProArray(), ));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i received the solution .Just added the index data with my database field name `(location:/var/www/magento/app/code/local/One/First/Block/Adminhtml/First/Grid.p‌​‌​hp)` 
----------->
`$this->addColumn('select_first',array( 'header' => Mage::helper('first')->__('Product Name'), 'width' => '150px', 'index' => 'proid', 'type' => 'options', 'options' => Mage::getSingleton('first/arrayf')->getProArray(), ));`

Answer (score 0):

```
 $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('attribute_set_id')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('type_id')
        ->joinField('qty',
            'cataloginventory/stock_item',
            'qty',
            'product_id=entity_id',
            '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
            'left')
        ->joinAttribute('status', 'catalog_product/status',
                        'entity_id', null, 'inner', $store->getId());
```

Now you have all products and respective status on $collection, you can do filter this way:

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', array(
'like' => array('status'),
));
```

Comment: $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', array(
'like' => array('status'),
));
where to add this part of code....

Comment: Anyplace, look..... When u get the collection, you can use this instruction to filter the collection, so... use when you want filter. If you prefer you can use after get the collection. Or on the code of collection, before ;

Comment: i received the solution .Just added the index data with my database field name (location:/var/www/magento/app/code/local/One/First/Block/Adminhtml/First/Grid.php)                                          -->$this->addColumn('select_first',array(
    'header' => Mage::helper('first')->__('Product Name'),
    'width' => '150px',
    'index' => 'proid',
    'type' => 'options',
    'options' => Mage::getSingleton('first/arrayf')->getProArray(),
    ));